# Proof for continuity

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity

> Theorem:
>
> Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m, f: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f$ is
>   continuous on $U \Leftrightarrow$ For all closed sets $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a closed set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$
>   such that $f^{-1}(T) = S \cap U$.

How to prove this theorem? If the word "closed" is replaced by "open", there is a proof using open balls.

Comment: Compliments of open sets are closed and vice versa. Use the topological definition of continuity (inverse images of open sets are open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is in fact not as trivial as it looks. It involves an important concept that the openness of a set depends on which metric space it is actually embedded.

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $U$, then for every closed set $T \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $T^c$ is open, hence $f^{-1}(T^c)$ is open relative to $U$. By the relative open set representation theorem (see, for example, Theorem $2.30$ of *Walter Rudin*'s *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*), there exists an open set $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$f^{-1}(T^c) = G \cap U.$$ On the other hand, notice that $U = f^{-1}(T^c) \cup f^{-1}(T)$, therefore
$$f^{-1}(T) = U \cap (f^{-1}(T^c))^c = U \cap (G \cap U)^c = G^c \cap U.$$
Take $S = G^c$ finishes the proof of the necessity part.

Conversely, for every open set $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $O^c$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence there exists $S$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$f^{-1}(O^c) = S \cap U.$$
The goal is to show that $f^{-1}(O)$ is open **relative to ${U}$** (note it is very possible that $f^{-1}(O)$ is not open relative to $\mathbb{R}^m$!). Again, we can use the relative open set representation theorem (the other direction) to deduce that
$$f^{-1}(O) = U \cap (f^{-1}(O^c))^c = U \cap (S^c \cup U^c) = S^c \cap U$$
is open relative to $U$, hence $f$ is continuous on $U$.

Answer (score 0):

The "only if" part will be proved, and you may try to do the other way around, which is similar. The definition of "$f$ is continuous on $U$" is this: for every $x \in U$ and every open ball $B_{\Bbb{R}^{n}}^{f(x)}$ formed over $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ of center $f(x)$, there is some open ball $B_{U}^{x}$ formed over $U$ of center $x$ such that $f(B_{U}^{x}) \subset B_{\Bbb{R}^{n}}^{f(x)}$.

Let $T$ be closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$; let $T' := \Bbb{R}^{n}\setminus T \cap f(U)  \neq \varnothing$. Then $T'$ is open in $f(U)$, implying that $f^{(-1)}(T')$ is open in $U$ by assumption. But
$$
f^{(-1)}(T') = \{ x \in U \mid f(x) \in f(U)\setminus T \} = U\setminus f^{(-1)}(T);
$$
hence $f^{(-1)}(T)$ is closed in $U$,
so there is some $S$ closed in $\Bbb{R}^{m}$ such that $f^{(-1)}(T) = S \cap U$.